# My FreeMarker method returns a string with ${variable} -- how to force FreeMarker to parse that?

Tags: freemarker

I've created a class that implements *TemplateMethodModelEx* from FreeMarker. Pretend the *exec()* function returns a String: **"Hello ${username}"**

I assign the class to a method in the data model:

```
dataModel.put("myMethod", myClassInstance);
dataModel.put("username", "John Doe");
```

My HTML template looks like this:

```
<p>${myMethod()}</p>
```

Which means that the following output is generated, when the template is processed:

```
<p>Hello ${username}</p>
```

Since there is actually a **username** value in my data model, I'd rather want the output to be:

```
<p>Hello John Doe</p>
```

How do I tell FreeMarker to parse the result of *myMethod()*? I tried both **?eval** and **?interpret** and both fail to accomplish what I want. Is this possible with FreeMarker?

Comment: Does your template starts with directive `[#ftl]` or `<#ftl>` ?
http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_ftl.html

Comment: There is no <#ftl> directive in my template. Is there a parameter I can set in an FTL directive to fix my situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove `${}` from a string to use `?eval`. Return `username` as a string from your method and use `?eval` or get variable from `.vars`.

```
<p>${classInstance.myMethod()?eval}</p>
```

or

```
<p>${.vars[classInstance.myMethod()]}</p>
```

If you want to return not just a variable name but a string with an expression (e.g. "Hello ${username}") from the method then use `?interpret`.

```
<#assign inlineTemplate = classInstance.myMethod()?interpret>
<@inlineTemplate />
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have updated my question -- in truth my class returns a sentence, where ${username} is part of the sentence. As such, I can't ?eval the whole thing.

Comment: That `#assign` can be eliminated: `<@classInstance.myMethod()?interpret />`

Comment: Yes of course, if that expression would be used only once than there is no point in `#assign`.