# How to parse/render Thymeleaf template twice in template

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, thymeleaf, freemarker

## controller.java  & test.shtml

```js
model.addAttribute('id',7449226)
String myTag="<a th:href='|https://stackoverflow.com/users/${id}/player7|'>link<a>"
model.addAttribute('myTag',myTag)
```

```html
<div th:utext="${myTag}">  <div>
```

## output result

```
<div> <a  href='https://stackoverflow.com/users/7449226/player7'> link <a>  <div>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25545966/my-freemarker-method-returns-a-string-with-variable-how-to-force-freemarke

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you want to do but i guess you want to dynamically evaluate `myTag` inside thymeleaf template.

This is done by ***preprocessing*** mechanism in Thymeleaf.

Here is a snippet of what you want to do:

```
<div th:utext="__${myTag}__"><div>
```

Please note the preprocessing **start tag** and **end tag** (*__$ __ respectively*)

For further information please take a look at the [link](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing).

Comment: Thanks for your inputs . .  The reason why I do this is That  Some templates are loaded from DB  . But It seems not works as expected when I use __$ __ :    Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "__${myTag}__"

Comment: Are you using it like `"__${myTag}"` or `"__${myTag}__"` . They are not the same

Comment: By the way there is another quick solution to your question if you like. You can just use `<div th:if="${id} != null"><a th:href="'https://stackoverflow.com/users/' + ${id} + '/player7'">link<a></div>`

Comment: . "Double underline ${myTag} Double underline"  of course.  The quick solution you mentioned is not adapting to this situation . Because myTag is stored in database and it may be changed by other users.And  myTag should be able to support all variables in the reference context like request or model.

Comment: Not *dash* it should be *underscore* but i guess you have already tried it. I am using this kind of mechanism nearly in all my projects. Nothing different. Another thing you can try is to generate the link in the controller. You know the `id` and you also have the `myTag` value coming from the database. Why not find the appropriate location of the `id` part and replace it with the `id` value you have. Then you have the required string which you can use in template with `th:utext`

Comment: After your edit, it is clear to me what you want to do. Are you getting any errors/exceptions? Please post it if so. Any logs etc.?